# Mirror Imaging pictures diagonally from bottom left to top right

Tags: python, image, for-loop, jython, mirror

I have some code I'm working on and I can't wrap my head around it.

I need to write the code so that the image is mirrored from bottom left to top right diagonally in that order, not top down. I've seen more complicated examples of this elsewhere but would like to see it solved similar to the below code:

I realize there are unused variables and bad coding generally.

I think I just need to change what's in the two for statements. What do you guys think?

```
def mirrorDiagBotLeftToTopRight():
    source = pickAFile()
    picOriginal = makePicture(source)
    mirrorPoint = getHeight(picOriginal)
    sourceY = getHeight(picOriginal)
    sourceX = getWidth(picOriginal)
    #mirrorPointWidth = width
    targetX = sourceX - 1
    targetY = sourceY - 1
    for x in range(targetX, 0):
        for y in range(0, mirrorPoint):
            OriginalPixel = getPixel(picOriginal, targetX, targetY)
            ReplacedPixel = getPixel(picOriginal, x + 1 ,targetY - 1)
            color = getColor(OriginalPixel)
            setColor(ReplacedPixel, color)
            targetY - 1

    mirrorPoint = targetX -1
    targetX + 1
    show(picOriginal)

mirrorDiagBotLeftToTopRight()
```

Comment: had issues with formatting the code with ``

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you need

```
mirrorPoint = getHeight(picOriginal)
targetX = sourceX - 1
targetY = sourceY - 1
```

but i would try something like this:

```
for x in range(0, sourceX):
        for y in range(0, sourceY):
            OriginalPixel = getPixel(picOriginal, sourceX - x, sourceY - y)
            ReplacedPixel = getPixel(picOriginal, x , y)
            color = getColor(OriginalPixel)
            setColor(ReplacedPixel, color)
```